# MongoDB - How to push an embedded array into an existing document

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Model:

```cs
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class UserPortfolioList
{
    public string? Username { get; set; }
    public List<Pflist>? Pflist { get; set; }

}

public class Pflist
{
    public string PfName { get; set; } = "DEFAULT NAME";
    public List<string>? Symbols { get; set; }

}
```

The existing MongoDB Document:

```
{
  "username": "aaa",
  "pflist": [
    {
      "pfName": "US TECH A",
      "symbols": [
        "GOOG",
        "MSFT"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The array I want to push (Same username, but different pfName and symbols)

```
{
  "username": "aaa",
  "pflist": [
    {
      "pfName": "US TECH C",
      "symbols": [
        "AAPL",
        "TSLA"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "username": "aaa",
  "pflist": [
    {
      "pfName": "US TECH A",
      "symbols": [
        "GOOG",
        "MSFT"
      ]
    },
    {
      "pfName": "US TECH C",
      "symbols": [
        "AAPL",
        "TSLA"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```cs
public async Task UpdateUserPfAsync(UserPortfolioList userPflist)

  await _UserPortfoliosCollection.UpdateOneAsync(Builders<UserPortfolioList>.Filter.Eq(
    "Username", userPflist.Username),
    Builders<UserPortfolioList>.Update.Push(x => x.Pflist, userPflist.Pflist));
```

The compiler throws out an error:

> can not convert lambda express to type......

I almost tried every approach on the StackOverflow, but none of them works for me.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Concern:**

Since you are adding a single object to `pflist`, you should use `userPflist.Pflist[0]` instead of `userPflist.Pflist` as with `userPflist.Pflist` will lead to the result:

```
{
  username: "aaa",
  pflist: [
    0: Object
    1: Array
      0: Object
  ]
}
```

---

**Push single element to the array**

MongoDB query:

```
db.collection.update({
  username: "aaa"
},
{
  $push: {
    "pflist": {
      "pfName": "US TECH C",
      "symbols": [
        "AAPL",
        "TSLA"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Push single element to the array)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zg1TyoVngyT)

MongoDB C#:

```cs
await _UserPortfoliosCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
    Builders<UserPortfolioList>.Filter.Eq("Username", userPflist.Username),
    Builders<UserPortfolioList>.Update.Push(x => x.Pflist, userPflist.Pflist[0]));
```

*Note: The lambda expression for `.Push()` works if the **value is an object** instead of an array.*

---

**Push multiple elements to the array**

To push multiple elements into the array, you need a `$each` operator.

MongoDB query:

```
db.collection.update({
  username: "aaa"
},
{
  $push: {
    "pflist": {
      $each: [
        {
          "pfName": "US TECH C",
          "symbols": [
            "AAPL",
            "TSLA"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9OaSbzy5WYu)

MongoDB C#:

```cs
await _UserPortfoliosCollection.UpdateOneAsync(
    Builders<UserPortfolioList>.Filter.Eq("Username", userPflist.Username),
    Builders<UserPortfolioList>.Update.PushEach(x => x.Pflist, userPflist.Pflist));
```

---

> Update Result

[image]

Comment: Great!!! Thanks!